# Display html page?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I want to load static web page from resource and to display it as dialog, not like its loaded in internet explorer but like dialog without any menus or borders if possible.
I want to use this page as "GUI", pretty crazy idea yes.

Someone can explain me how to achieve this ? (I dont want any dependencies on my executable).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/article.php/c4379/Display-a-Web-Page-in-a-Plain-C-Win32-Application.htm) a good read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a webbrowser like this:

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/mshtml/index.html

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315617/es

Comment: Yeah i think thats what i am looking for 'Embedded HTML in Window', i can make it display the just the HTML page without any borders and menus around it right ?